# How to implement Autocomplete functionality in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, autocomplete

I am trying to make a autocomplete functionality for selecting fonts where the rest of the text must be selected apart from the text inserted by the user.

How to implement Autocomplete functionality in tkinter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Imports**

```
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
```

**Setting up the widgets**

```
    class AutoComplete:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.title('AutoComplete')

            self.ent_var = StringVar()
            self.entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.ent_var, width=50)
            self.entry.pack()

            self.list_var = Variable(self.entry)
            self.listbox = Listbox(self.root, listvariable=self.list_var, width=50)
            self.listbox.pack()

            self.all_fonts = list(font.families())
            self.all_fonts.sort()
            self.all_fonts = self.all_fonts[26:]
            self.non_duplicates_fonts()
            self.lower_case = [f.lower() for f in self.all_fonts]

            self.list_var.set(self.all_fonts)
            self.entry.focus()

            self.root.resizable(0, 0)
            self.root.mainloop()

        def non_duplicates_fonts(self):
            '''Filter fonts starting with same name'''

            prev_family = ' '
            font_families = []

            for family in self.all_fonts:
                if not family.startswith(prev_family):
                    font_families.append(family)
                    prev_family = family

            self.all_fonts = font_families
```

**Setting default values**

```
def default(self):
    '''Set default values in entry widget and listbox'''

    self.listbox.selection_set(3)
    self.ent_var.set('Arial')

    self.entry.config(insertofftime=1000000, insertontime=0)
    self.set_selection()
```

> To make a auto-complete functionality in **tkinter**, you need to bind
> your text widget with bindtags **<KeyPress>** to detect if any keys
> are pressed down.

### When keys are pressed down then you need to check:

- Convert **space** to " "
- Store each pressed key to a variable only if that key is printable
- If selection is present in **Entry** widget then remove the selected text and insert the keys pressed along with the text present in **Entry** widget and shift the **CURSOR** to one step forward. Also store the starting index by increasing by 1 so that we can use it to select the remaining text.

  If selection is absent then increase the starting index by 1 and repeat the remaining.

  ```
   def key_pressed(self, event=None):
       key = event.keysym

       if key == 'space':
           key = ' '

       if key in string.printable:
           if self.entry.selection_present():
               self.sel = self.entry.index('sel.first') + 1
               self.entry.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')

           else:
               self.sel = self.entry.index('insert') + 1

           value = self.ent_var.get() + key
           self.ent_var.set(value)
           self.ent_index += 1

           self.entry.icursor(self.ent_index)
           self.auto_complete()  # Explained below

       return 'break'
  ```
- Bind **Entry** widget with bindtag **<KeyPress>**

  ```
    self.entry.bind('<KeyPress>', self.key_pressed)
  ```

### When backspace key is pressed

- If **cursor** position has not reached to the beginning of the **Entry** widget.

  - If selection is present then remove the selected value and set the cursor index to the length of the remaining text and set blinking time back to default.
  - If selection is not present then just remove the last value from the **Entry** widget and insert rest of to the **Entry** widget and decrease the cursor index by 1.

    ```
      def backspace(self, event=None):
          value = self.entry.get()[:-1]
          self.ent_var.set(value)

          if self.ent_index != 0:
              if self.entry.selection_present():
                  self.entry.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')
                  self.ent_index = len(self.ent_var.get())

                  if self.entry['insertofftime'] == 1000000:  # Restore time of blinking to default
                      self.entry.config(insertofftime=300, insertontime=600)

              else:
                  self.ent_index -= 1

          return 'break'
    ```
- Bind **Entry** widget with bindtag **<BackSpace>**

  ```
    self.entry.bind('<BackSpace>', self.backspace)
  ```

### When tab key is pressed

- Select all text in **Entry** widget
- Set cursor to the end of the **Entry** widget and remove blinking
- Remove previous selection from the **listbox** and select the new value in **listbox**

  ```
    def tab_completion(self, event=None):
        '''Select all text in entry widget of matched one.
           Also select the same value in listbox'''

        value = self.ent_var.get()

        self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')
        self.entry.icursor('end')

        index = self.all_fonts.index(value)
        self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
        self.listbox.selection_set(index)

        self.entry.config(insertofftime=1000000, insertontime=0)  # Removing blinking of cursor.
        return 'break'
  ```
- Bind **Entry** widget with bindtag **<Tab>**

  ```
    self.entry.bind('<Tab>', self.tab_completion)
  ```

### When UP key is pressed

- Select value above the selection in **listbox** until the index reaches to 0
- Insert just selected value to **entry** widget from **listbox** and select all text in **entry** widget

  ```
    def up_direction(self, event=None):
        '''Move selection in upwards direction in listbox'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        if index > 0:
            index -= 1

            self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
            self.listbox.selection_set(index)
            self.listbox.see(index)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
            self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')

        return 'break'
  ```
- Bind **Entry** widget with bindtag **<Up>**

  ```
    self.entry.bind('<Up>', self.up_direction)
  ```

### When DOWN button is pressed

- Select value below the selection in **listbox** until the index reaches to the **total number of values** in **listbox**.
- Insert just selected value to **entry** widget from **listbox** and select all text in **entry** widget

  ```
    def down_direction(self, event=None):
        '''Move selection in downwards direction in listbox'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        if index < len(self.all_fonts) - 1:
            index += 1

            self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
            self.listbox.selection_set(index)
            self.listbox.see(index)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
            self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')

        return 'break'
  ```
- Bind **Entry** widget with bindtag **<Down>**

  ```
    self.entry.bind('<Down>', self.down_direction)
  ```

> Here, **return 'break' forbids tkinter to execute its default bindings**

### When selection is made by clicking value in listbox

- Insert the selected value from **listbox** in **entry** widget

  ```
    def button_click(self, event=None):
        '''When selection is made by clicking'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
        self.root.after(10, self.set_selection)
  ```
- Select all text in **entry** widget

  ```
    def set_selection(self):
        '''Select all text in entry widget'''

        self.entry.select_range(0, 'end')
        self.entry.focus()
  ```
- Bind **ListBox** widget with bindtag **<<ListboxSelect>>**

  ```
    self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.button_click)
  ```

### Auto-Complete function explanation

- Grab value from the **Entry** widget
- Get matched value from the list of list-box with respect to the text entered in **Entry** widget
- If **matched** is non-empty then grab its first value and get its index and insert that value in **Entry** widget and if the **cursor** index is equal to the first matched value then select all text in **Entry** widget else select from the recent inserted value index to the **end** and scroll the **listbox** to the index of the first matched value

  ```
    def auto_complete(self):
        value = self.ent_var.get().strip().lower()
        matched = [f for f in self.lower_case if f.startswith(value)]

        if matched:
            matched = matched[0]
            index = self.lower_case.index(matched)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])

            if self.entry.index('insert') == len(matched):
                self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')

            else:
                self.entry.selection_range(self.sel, 'end')

            self.listbox.see(index)
  ```

### Putting everything together

```
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font


class AutoComplete:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ent_index = 0

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('AutoComplete')

        self.ent_var = StringVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.ent_var, width=50)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.list_var = Variable(self.entry)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.root, listvariable=self.list_var, exportselection=False, activestyle='none', selectmode=SINGLE, width=50)
        self.listbox.pack()

        self.all_fonts = list(font.families())
        self.all_fonts.sort()
        self.all_fonts = self.all_fonts[26:]
        self.non_duplicates_fonts()
        self.lower_case = [f.lower() for f in self.all_fonts]

        self.list_var.set(self.all_fonts)
        self.entry.focus()

        self.entry.bind('<Up>', self.up_direction)
        self.entry.bind('<Tab>', self.tab_completion)
        self.entry.bind('<BackSpace>', self.backspace)
        self.entry.bind('<Down>', self.down_direction)
        self.entry.bind('<KeyPress>', self.key_pressed)
        self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.button_click)

        self.default()

        self.root.resizable(0, 0)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def non_duplicates_fonts(self):
        '''Filter fonts starting with same name'''

        prev_family = ' '
        font_families = []

        for family in self.all_fonts:
            if not family.startswith(prev_family):
                font_families.append(family)
                prev_family = family

        self.all_fonts = font_families

    def default(self):
        '''Set default values in entry widget and listbox'''

        self.listbox.selection_set(3)
        self.ent_var.set('Arial')

        self.entry.config(insertofftime=1000000, insertontime=0)
        self.set_selection()

    def key_pressed(self, event=None):
        key = event.keysym

        if key == 'space':
            key = ' '

        if key in string.printable:
            if self.entry.selection_present():
                self.sel = self.entry.index('sel.first') + 1
                self.entry.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')

            else:
                self.sel = self.entry.index('insert') + 1

            value = self.ent_var.get() + key
            self.ent_var.set(value)
            self.ent_index += 1

            self.entry.icursor(self.ent_index)
            self.auto_complete()

        return 'break'

    def backspace(self, event=None):
        value = self.entry.get()[:-1]
        self.ent_var.set(value)

        if self.ent_index != 0:
            if self.entry.selection_present():
                self.entry.delete('sel.first', 'sel.last')
                self.ent_index = len(self.ent_var.get())

                if self.entry['insertofftime'] == 1000000:  # Restore time of blinking to default
                    self.entry.config(insertofftime=300, insertontime=600)

            else:
                self.ent_index -= 1

        return 'break'

    def tab_completion(self, event=None):
        '''Select all text in entry widget of matched one.
           Also select the same value in listbox'''

        value = self.ent_var.get()

        self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')
        self.entry.icursor('end')

        index = self.all_fonts.index(value)
        self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
        self.listbox.selection_set(index)

        self.entry.config(insertofftime=1000000, insertontime=0)
        return 'break'

    def auto_complete(self):
        value = self.ent_var.get().strip().lower()
        matched = [f for f in self.lower_case if f.startswith(value)]

        if matched:
            matched = matched[0]
            index = self.lower_case.index(matched)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])

            if self.entry.index('insert') == len(matched):
                self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')
                self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
                self.listbox.selection_set(index)

            else:
                self.entry.selection_range(self.sel, 'end')

            self.listbox.see(index)

    def down_direction(self, event=None):
        '''Move selection in downwards direction in listbox'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        if index < len(self.all_fonts) - 1:
            index += 1

            self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
            self.listbox.selection_set(index)
            self.listbox.see(index)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
            self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')

        return 'break'

    def up_direction(self, event=None):
        '''Move selection in upwards direction in listbox'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        if index > 0:
            index -= 1

            self.listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
            self.listbox.selection_set(index)
            self.listbox.see(index)

            self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
            self.entry.selection_range(0, 'end')

        return 'break'

    def button_click(self, event=None):
        '''When selection is made by clicking'''

        index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

        self.ent_var.set(self.all_fonts[index])
        self.root.after(10, self.set_selection)

    def set_selection(self):
        '''Select all text in entry widget'''

        self.entry.select_range(0, 'end')
        self.entry.focus()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AutoComplete()
```